# How to identify form data using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using this website https://secure.wufoo.com/gallery/templates/forms/change-of-major/ for testing.I am unable to fill data in any field.Could anyone please help me for this?

Comment: What code you have done?

Comment: package launching;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class drag {
 public WebDriver driver;
 @Test
  public void f() throws InterruptedException {
  driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://secure.wufoo.com/gallery/templates/forms/change-of-major/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//input[@id='Field110']")).sendKeys("raghu");

Comment: @RijoMon: Please edit your question and add the code to the **question**

Answer (score 1):

That form is in iframe so you can access form fields as per below way :

```
    driver.get("https://secure.wufoo.com/gallery/templates/forms/change-of-major/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("wufooFormps9rvma1pg446z")));  

    driver.findElement(By.id("Field106")).sendKeys("raghu");

    driver.findElement(By.id("Field107")).sendKeys("mon");
```

So in above code we move to iframe first and then found elements.